# FFmpeg. Processing new jpeg files that appear

Tags: ffmpeg, video-recording

I have a directory where new files in jpeg format are periodically emerge.

How can these files be processed one by one,
waiting for the next one and convert them to a mp4 file.

I tried like this

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i test%d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

but ffmpeg do not wait for new files and exits.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Try https://superuser.com/questions/1375257

Comment: Thanks, interesting information